# How to open chrome browser in my windows form without third party component in c#?

Tags: c#

I placed the web browser inside the windows form and try to navigate to a URL which was working in chrome, but web browser doesn't allow it to work because it is using IE. How do I change from IE to chrome in web browser control?

Comment: Your choices are mainly `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` (edge) or `CefSharp` (chromium). Only the ancient IE WebView is distributed with windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
strURL="http://myurl.com";
try
{
//Launch Chrome in a new window
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome", strURL+" --new-window");             
}
catch
{
try
{ 
    //Chrome not found ... launch Firefox in a new window
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox", "-new-window "+ strURL);
}
catch
{
    //WARN THE USER TO INSTALL A BROWSER...
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure how launching a browser fixes the web browser embedded in a Windows Form!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).